# Execute a script every random number with nodejs

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I want to execute a script with a random interval between 11 to 13 minutes. I tried this code, but the script is execute in much less than 11 minutes. Is my calculation wrong?

```
setInterval(function() {
  // code to be executed
  const script = spawn('node', ['index.js']);

}, 1000 * 60 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 11); // 1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * random number of minutes between 11 and 13
```

Comment: `setInterval` calls in fixed interval, if you want different intervals, you have to call `setTimeout` with a new random interval every time ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you are missing parenthesis.
It should be `1000 * 60 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 11)` instead of `1000 * 60 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 11)`

Secondly, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` can only take 3 possible values (0, 1 or 2), so your script will run either every 11, 12 or 13 minutes.
If you want more possible values between 11 and 13 minutes, you can compute the time interval this way:
`Math.floor(1000 * 60 * (Math.random() * 3 + 11))` to have many possible values between 11 and 13 minutes.

This will do the job:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // code to be executed
  const script = spawn('node', ['index.js']);

}, Math.floor(1000 * 60 * (Math.random() * 3 + 11)); // 1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * random number of minutes between 11 and 13
```